# Duplicate entry error when scheduling a large number of DAGs concurrently

Tags: python, datetime, airflow

I am running this test:

```
from unittest import TestCase

from backend.tasks.airflow import trigger_dag


class TestTriggerDag(TestCase):

    def test_trigger_dag(self):
        trigger_dag("update_game_dag", game_id=99)
        trigger_dag("update_game_dag", game_id=100)
        trigger_dag("update_game_dag", game_id=101)
        trigger_dag("update_game_dag", game_id=102)
        trigger_dag("update_game_dag", game_id=103)
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

The internals of `trigger_dag` are:

```
from typing import List
import random
import time

from airflow.api.client.local_client import Client
from airflow.models.dagrun import DagRun

afc = Client(None, None)

...
def get_dag_run_state(dag_id: str, run_id: str):
    return DagRun.find(dag_id=dag_id, run_id=run_id)[0].state


def trigger_dag(dag_id: str, wait_for_complete: bool = False, **kwargs):
    run_hash = '%030x' % random.randrange(16**30)
    kwarg_list = [f"{str(k)}:{str(v)}" for k, v in kwargs.items()]
    run_id = f"{run_hash}-{'_'.join(kwarg_list)}"
    afc.trigger_dag(dag_id, run_id=run_id, conf=kwargs)
    while wait_for_complete and get_dag_run_state(dag_id, run_id) == "running":
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
    return get_dag_run_state(dag_id, run_id)
```

This throws the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry 'update_game_dag-2020-08-30 00:30:13.000000' for key 'dag_run.dag_id'")
[SQL: INSERT INTO dag_run (dag_id, execution_date, start_date, end_date, state, run_id, external_trigger, conf) VALUES (%(dag_id)s, %(execution_date)s, %(start_date)s, %(end_date)s, %(state)s, %(run_id)s, %(external_trigger)s, %(conf)s)]
[parameters: {'dag_id': 'update_game_dag', 'execution_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 30, 0, 30, 13), 'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 30, 0, 30, 13, 262676), 'end_date': None, 'state': 'running', 'run_id': '3129c0272d7e3e5f018d04d2debf06-game_id:101', 'external_trigger': 1, 'conf': b'\x80\x04\x95\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94\x8c\x07game_id\x94Kes.'}]
```

It looks like the issue is that when logging the DAG run to the `dag_run` metadata table, the `execution_date` column timestamp is being saved at the second (`datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 30, 0, 30, 13),`), rather than microseconds, resolution. When firing a bunch of DAG runs off at the same time this creates a duplicate entry conflict. Interesting to note that `start_date` doesn't work this way: it preserves the microsecond information (`datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 30, 0, 30, 13, 262676)`).

Is this a feature or a bug? Does airflow not allow multiple externally triggered DAG runs to be started in the same second interval for a given DAG id deliberately? Is there a quick fix for this, or should I send a PR or ASF Jira issue ticket?

In case it's relevant, I want to do this because I have a bunch of assets that I need to update at the game level for all users on our app on a 5-minute cadence. We use celery beat as our application scheduler, not airflow. Where airflow really shines is in coordinating the execution of the task graph over an elastically scaling worker cluster. So every 5-minutes I want to be able to say "hey, airflow, please trigger DAGS for this 200 games." The DAG has game id awareness from the `conf` data that we pass to the DAG context along with the external API call.

Answer (score 1):

Kept at it for a few more minutes and found the solution. `local_client` from `from airflow.api.client.local_client import Client` just bundles up a base class from `airflow.api.client` with a couple of methods from  `airflow.api.common.experimental`:

```
from airflow.api.client import api_client
from airflow.api.common.experimental import pool
from airflow.api.common.experimental import trigger_dag
from airflow.api.common.experimental import delete_dag


class Client(api_client.Client):
    """Local API client implementation."""

    def trigger_dag(self, dag_id, run_id=None, conf=None, execution_date=None):
        dag_run = trigger_dag.trigger_dag(dag_id=dag_id,
                                          run_id=run_id,
                                          conf=conf,
                                          execution_date=execution_date)
        return "Created {}".format(dag_run)

    def delete_dag(self, dag_id):
        count = delete_dag.delete_dag(dag_id)
        return "Removed {} record(s)".format(count)

    def get_pool(self, name):
        the_pool = pool.get_pool(name=name)
        return the_pool.pool, the_pool.slots, the_pool.description

    def get_pools(self):
        return [(p.pool, p.slots, p.description) for p in pool.get_pools()]

    def create_pool(self, name, slots, description):
        the_pool = pool.create_pool(name=name, slots=slots, description=description)
        return the_pool.pool, the_pool.slots, the_pool.description

    def delete_pool(self, name):
        the_pool = pool.delete_pool(name=name)
        return the_pool.pool, the_pool.slots, the_pool.description
```

Kind of an odd approach, because none of the class methods here actually invoke the `api_client.Client` base class. `trigger_dag` from `airflow.api.common.experimental` has an argument `replace_microseconds`. This is where the information is getting scrubbed.

Invoking `airflow.api.common.experimental.trigger_dag` directly with `replace_microseconds=True` solves my problem:

```
from typing import List
import random
import time

from airflow.api.common.experimental import trigger_dag
from airflow.models.dagrun import DagRun


def log_headline(keys: tuple, values: List):
    headline_ls = [f"{key} = {value}" for key, value in zip(keys, values)]
    print("\n \n*** ARGUMENTS ***\n-----------------\n" + ", ".join(headline_ls) + "\n-----------------\n")


def context_parser(context: dict, *args: str):
    """*args looks for an inventory of names from the context that we expect a given task to have access to. Use of
    the .get access method means that misses names will default to None rather than generate a key error"""
    return_values = [context['dag_run'].conf.get(arg) for arg in args]
    log_headline(args, return_values)
    return return_values


def get_dag_run_state(dag_id: str, run_id: str):
    return DagRun.find(dag_id=dag_id, run_id=run_id)[0].state


def start_dag(dag_id: str, wait_for_complete: bool = False, **kwargs):
    run_hash = '%030x' % random.randrange(16**30)
    kwarg_list = [f"{str(k)}:{str(v)}" for k, v in kwargs.items()]
    run_id = f"{run_hash}-{'_'.join(kwarg_list)}"
    trigger_dag.trigger_dag(dag_id, run_id=run_id, conf=kwargs, replace_microseconds=False)
    while wait_for_complete and get_dag_run_state(dag_id, run_id) == "running":
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
    return get_dag_run_state(dag_id, run_id)
```